# Measurability of $u(x-y):(\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n, \sigma(\mathscr{L}^n\times\mathscr{L}^n)) \rightarrow (R,\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets, fubini-tonelli-theorems

When we define the convolution on $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, we are interested to proof that $\forall f,g \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then $f\star g \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
In the proof of this we want use the Fubini-Tonelli for said that:

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|u(x-y)v(y)|dydx = \\ =\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|u(x-y)v(y)|dxdy$

But for that is sufficient to say that:

$u(x-y):(\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n, \sigma(\mathscr{L}^n\times\mathscr{L}^n)) \rightarrow (R,\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$

is measurable. However i don't how ti proof this fact.

Comment: It is the composition of $u$ and the continuous map $(x,y) \to x-y$.

Comment: No f(u(x)) is measurable if f is continuous and u lebesgue measurable, but in general u(f(x)) no, because the lebesgue sigma algebra contains stricktly the borel sigma algebra.

Comment: Approximate $u$ by Borel functions (every integrable Lebesgue measurable function is the a.s. limit of sequences of Borel functions).

Comment: See pp. 168-170 fo Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, 3rd edition for more details. $f=g+h$ where $g$ is Borel measurable and $h=0$ a.s.

Comment: See [Is composition of Lebesgue measurable function and addition Lebesgue measurable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4289185/568204).

Comment: @ManuelBonanno: as stated in the reference that I sent you, you can replace $f$ and $g$ by Borel measurable functions:  $f=f_0$, $g=g_0$ a.s. for some Borel measurable functions $f_0$ and $g_0$. The rest is as stated in the reference.